# Firebase checking if child exists, pull and update data if exists javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to **count** the number of times a certain key word (city) is searched.  I have stored the data so for each new input I want to see if the child exists and if so pull the numSearched child and add 1.  I can see if it exists but I can add on.
My database is a simple

```
file:///Users/paulamactavish/Downloads/practicaltravel-63ff1-export.json
var cityToCheck = city;
var cityRef = firebase.database().ref('travelPlans');
cityRef.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        if (snapshot.val().city==cityToCheck) {
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(snapshot);
            var citySearch = JSON.parse(myJSON)
            numSearchCounter = (citySearch.numSearched);
            numSearchCounter++  
            child.ref().update({
                numSearched = numSearchCounter
            });
        };         
    });
});
```

I have looked over lots of other responses but I cant seem to make it work as a whole.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure, show us a snippet of the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots) under `cityRef`. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: got it.  The link is above.  Thanks for taking the time to look at it!!!!